# Display imagesc with custom values on x- and y-axis

Tags: matlab, axis-labels, image-scaling

I'm using MATLABS function imagesc to plot a 6x6 matrix of doubles. This is the plot I get:

[image: Plot]

What I want to do is change the values on the x- and y-axis to values that I choose myself.

For example, I want to replace the values 1-6 with my own vector [10, 16, 53, 97, 136 191] so that they are displayed on the x- and/or y-axis.

Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can modify the `XTickLabel` and `YTickLabel` properties for this.

In MATLAB r2014b or higher you should:

```
ax=gca;
ax.XTickLabel = {'10', '16', '53', '97', '136', '191'};
ax.YTickLabel = {'10', '16', 'look a banana', '97', 'yeah you can write whatever', '191'};
```

In previous versions do

```
ax=gca;
set(ax,'XTickLabel',{'10', '16', '53', '97', '136', '191'})
set(ax,'YTickLabel',{'10', '16', 'look a banana', '97', 'yeah you can write whatever', '191'})
```

More info:

[Change Axis Tick Value Locations and Labels, The Mathworks](https://uk.mathworks.com/help/matlab/creating_plots/change-tick-marks-and-tick-labels-of-graph-1.html)